# Multiselect search whole string

Tags: search, extjs, multi-select

I have a multiselect with search bound to a store (with attribute string_value). Search only searches strings that start with "string to search" instead of contains "string to search" (similar to searching for '%string%' instead of 'string%'). Is there a way to do this by extending 'multiselector-search'?

Below is my multiselector control bound to a form:

```
var ms = Ext.widget('form', {
    xtype: 'multi-selector',
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    requires: [
    'Ext.view.MultiSelector'
    ],
    layout: 'fit',

    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        bbar: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'button',
            html: 'Toolbar here',

            text: 'Submit request to API',

            // get submitted array
            handler: function() {
                if (cardioCatalogQT.config.mode === 'test') {
                    console.log('In submitted values handler: ');
                }

                var submitted = Ext.getCmp('test');

                var dx = [];
                Ext.Array.each(submitted.store.data.items, function (item) {
                    dx.push(item.data.string_value);
                }); // each()

                Ext.Msg.alert('Submitted Values',
                   'The following diagnoses will be sent to the server:  <br      
                />' + dx);

                if (cardioCatalogQT.config.mode === 'test') {
                    console.log(dx);
                }
            }
        }],
        xtype: 'multiselector',
        title: 'Selected Dx',

        id: 'test',
        name:'test',
        fieldName: 'string_value',

        viewConfig: {
            deferEmptyText: false,
            emptyText: 'No Dx selected'
        },
        // TODO: fix ability to remove selected items when box is unchecked
        search: {
            field: 'string_value',
           store: 'Diagnoses'

        }
    }]
}).center();
```

The closest I could find to this problem was http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?240887. I tried making it work with the multiselect search with no success.

Comment: Perhaps you can add an example of what you are doing on fiddle.sencha.com and we can easier try to help you.

Comment: Done: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jav 

Use case would be that I want to search for all instances of a number in my string, say '0.' Instead of typing the full value ('string_0'), simply typing '0' should get me all desired instances from the list (suppose there was also 'string_10' in the list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MultiSelector uses the Ext.util.Filter to narrow the results based on the typed text.  You need to enable the [anyMatch](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Filter-cfg-anyMatch) property for it to match anywhere.

To do that, you'll have to include a new "search" function in your multiselector's search object that will have anyMatch=true.

Please see my fiddle, https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jf5, for an example of how to do this.