# Kendo Multiselect Search Full Text Search

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, dojo, full-text-search, kendo-multiselect

I am using Kendo Multiselect: http://dojo.telerik.com/EWiyo

In my demo I have three options in the select box, those are:

```
var data = [
            {Name: "Swiss Stock Exchange SIX", Id: 220},
            {Name: "Stock Exchange Oslo OBX", Id: 315},
            {Name: "Frankfurt Xetra", Id: 115}
          ];
```

Now typing "Swiss" finds the "Swiss Stock Exchange SIX"

BUT: Typing "SIX" does not find anything. I want to have a "full text search" rather than it just searching from the beginning of the textvalues.

I have found following but I am unsure how to implement this with kendo: [Multiselect search whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974034/multiselect-search-whole-string)

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add `filter: "contains"` to your multiselect options:

```
$("#multi").kendoMultiSelect({
    ...
    filter: "contains"
});
```