# Changing anyMatch default for Filter.JS in ExtJS for MultiSelect search

Tags: search, extjs, filter, multi-select

I have a multiselect bound to a store in which I implemented use of `anyMatch: true` to allow for `True to allow any match - no regex start/end line anchors will be added` (as per the comment in Filter.js). My problem is that I need to implement this as per the answer to [multiselect-search-whole-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974034/multiselect-search-whole-string), in particular the solution provided in this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jf5

What I want to do is just set `anyMatch: true`, regardless, so I set it in Filter.js, but this has no effect on use of it. I searched the entire codebase for other instances of `anyMatch: false` and the only other one is in `ext-all-debug.js`. Why isn't setting these values having any effect? I don't see where else this default value could be set?

**EDIT 1**

I tried a different override, and while it is not exhibiting the right behavior, it is actually doing something this time. I figured that since the chunk of code that does work when embedded in the `search` attribute within the MultiSelector control was pretty much what was found in the MultiSelectorSearch's `search` method, that this was what I needed to focus on for the override. Any suggestions on tweaking this would be most welcome:

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.view.MultiSelectorSearch', {
    override: 'Ext.view.MultiSelectorSearch',

    search: function (text, me) {
        var filter = me.searchFilter,
            filters = me.getSearchStore().getFilters();

        if (text) {
            filters.beginUpdate();

            if (filter) {
                filter.setValue(text);
            } else {
                me.searchFilter = filter = new Ext.util.Filter({
                    id: 'search',
                    property: me.field,
                    value: text,
                    anyMatch: true
                });
            }

            filters.add(filter);

            filters.endUpdate();
        } else if (filter) {
            filters.remove(filter);
        }
    }

});
```

**EDIT 2**

Got it! The key was that originally, since this code was embedded in a singleton, I could reference the method by passing `me` from the calling form.panel. This did not work globally as an override, and required me to define the method as

```
search: function (text) {
     var me = this,
```

I hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

Changing in ext-all-debug.js is not safe, when you do a production build this file will not get included.

Best way is to override the Filter class, here is how you can do it.

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.util.Filter', {
    override: 'Ext.util.Filter',

    anyMatch: true
});
```

And import this class in Application.js

```
Ext.require([
   'Ext.overrides.util.Filter'
]);
```

Comment: I was going to try an override, but I figured if it wasn't working through direct manipulation of Filter.js then it wouldn't work, and sure enough, an override isn't working. I have other overrides, so I implemented this like them. I edited your answer, but apparently it has to undergo peer review. Anyway, I changed the namespace to be 'Ext.overrides.util.Filter' and the class to be imported in Application.js.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, especially since the change I made to the search attribute based on the above fiddle basically is doing the same thing with `anyMatch: true`, just from a different place.

Comment: I gave you a point for steering me toward the override after initially thinking it would do no good.